# Linq - Filter a Result set based on another query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my DB structure Each EmployeeId can have multiple BusinessId’s

In my 1st query I am getting the BusinessId’s of an employee based his EmployeeId

```
List<int> businessId = EMPDB.BusinessEmployees.where(a =>  a.EmployeeId == 5678 && a.Active == true).Select(S => s.BusinessId).ToList();
```

Out of the above BusinessIds I want to filter and get only those BusinessIds who have non compliance I.e there BusinessId is present in the BusinessCompliance table.

`List<int> complianceBusinessIds = EMPDB.BusinessCompliances.where( m=> businessId.Contains(m.BusinessId)).ToList();`  —- this is throwing error and I am not able to achieve this

Comment: If there is a relationship between Business and BusinessCompliances, and between Employee and Business via EmployeeBusinesses, why can't you select the Business for the employee and then ask the Business what its Compliances are?

Comment: Actually.. I'm even more confused - you already know the businessId because you put it as an input to the first query; this first query cannot return you anything other than a repeated list of the same business ID 5678, one repetition for every active employee. What has employee got to do with anything? Why are you not just doing `EMPDB.BusinessCompliances.where(bc => bc.BusinessId == 5678).ToList()` ?

Comment: I have selected all the BusinessId’s for an EmployeeId and out of those I am trying to get those BusinessId’s which have compliance i.e they are present in the BusinessCompliance table.. so that i can display all these BusinessId’s in a report to the user when he logs In

Comment: *"I have selected all the BusinessId’s for an EmployeeId"* - you've selected all the BusinessIDs for a BusinessID

Comment: Really my bad in typing my query...I have updated my post

Comment: Now it makes more sense. Tell us what the error is. Never say "I got error" without giving the exact exception message

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a join?

```
        from be in EMPDB.BusinessEmployees
        join bc in EMPDB.BusinessCompliances on be.BusinessId equals bc.BusinessId
        where be.EmployeeID == 5678
        select bc;
```

It should be the better performance way to answer things like this